# Which of these are vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I determine which ones are vector spaces or subspaces to known vector spaces ?

$\big\{p(t)\in\mathbb P_3:p(7)=0\big\}$

$\big[-1,1\,\big]=\big\{x\in\mathbb R:-1\leqslant x\leqslant1\big\}$

$\left\{x\in\mathbb R^4:x_1+x_3=0\right\}$

$\left\{A\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}:AA^T=I_2\right\}$

Comment: You see whether they satisfy the [axioms of a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition_and_basic_properties)

Comment: ... or whether they are subspaces to a known vector space, which is simpler because you have only to check that the given set $S$ is stable for addition ($u,v \in S \implies u+v \in S$) and for external multiplication ($u \in S, a \in \mathbb{R} \implies a.u \in S$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the sets you are given subsets of vector spaces. So, the only checks that you need to make are whether these sets are closed under addition , closed under scalar multiplication and contain the additive identity of the parent vector space.

Let's take the first set $$U=\{p\in P_3 : p(7)=0\}$$ First you need to verify if for $p, q\in U$, we have that $p+q\in U$. To do this, you just have to verify that $(p+q)(7)=0$. This should be easy as the usual definition of addition on $P_3$ is defined by $(p+q)(x)=p(x)+q(x)$. Thus, for $p, q\in U$, we have that $(p+q)(7)=p(7)+q(7)=0+0=0$. Thus, the subset $U$ is closed under addition.

Now you have to check whether the subset is closed under scalar multiplication. Which means that for $\lambda \in F$ and $p\in U$, is $(\lambda p)\in U$. The usual definition of scalar multiplication on $P_3$ is $(\lambda p)(x)=\lambda p(x)$. So, let $p\in U$ and $\lambda \in F$. Then $(\lambda p)(7)=\lambda p(7)=\lambda 0=0$. Thus, the subset $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Now you just have to verify whether the subset contains the additive identity of $P_3$. Fortunately this happens to be true as $0(x)\in U$ because $0(7)=0$. Here the symbol $0$ denotes the polynomial $p(x)=0$ for all $x\in F$.

Once you have verified these three conditions to be true, you can conclude that the given subset is a subspace.

---

Make the same checks on other subsets to determine whether they are subspaces or not.